# How can dates be formatted with Tooltip in a DateListPlot?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, tooltip

After creating an association of time series as follows:

```
stocks = {"AAPL", "FB"};
prices = FinancialData[stocks, {{2019, 11, 1}, {2019, 11, 15}}];
stockPrices = AssociationThread[stocks, prices];
```

I plot with:

```
DateListPlot[Tooltip[stockPrices]]
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to format the dates in the tooltip in a more conventional form, e.g. mm/dd/yy.

[image]

Also, how can one create tooltips with just the value, excluding the date.  The documentation for Tooltip is pretty thin.

Comment: `DateListPlot[Tooltip[stockPrices]] /. 
 Tooltip[pt_, {date_, price_}] :> 
  Tooltip[pt, {DateString[
     DateList@date, {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "YearShort"}], price}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
stocks = {"AAPL", "FB"};
prices = FinancialData[stocks, {{2019, 11, 1}, {2019, 11, 15}}];
stockPrices = AssociationThread[stocks, prices];
tooltip[expr : {date_, value_}] := Tooltip[expr, DateString[date]]

DateListPlot[
 (tooltip /@ Normal[#]) & /@ stockPrices
 ]
```

[image: Tooltip demo]

Comment: that works and it's very easy to extend to create tooltips with just the value.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative procedure is to recognize that `DateListPlot[]` uses [absolute time](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTime.html) as the abscissa, and then construct a replacement rule using `DateString[]`. Using the same data as in C.E.'s answer:

```
DateListPlot[Tooltip[stockPrices]] /.
Tooltip[obj_, {at_, val_}] :> Tooltip[obj, DateString[at]]
```

Use the second argument of `DateString[]` if you want to modify the format used in the tooltips.

Comment: Yes, that knowledge is helpful.  The combination of ReplaceAll and RuleDelayed looks quite powerful.